# Найти многочисленные вхождения в строке

Tags: javascript, html

Я делаю запрос на онлайн каталог запчастей, и получаю одну очень длинную строку, которая содержит все данные (это html страница). Такая строка например:

```js
window['__INITIAL_STATE__'] = {
  "about": {
    "requisites": [],
    "__merged": true
  },
  "abTest": [],
  "actualLocation": {
    "loading": false,
    "pathname": "\u002Fgoods\u002F2108101200508\u002Favtovaz\u002Fid99426615",
    "location": {
      "type": "APPRAISE_PRODUCT",
      "payload": {
        "article": "2108101200508",
        "brand": "avtovaz",
        "articleId": 99426615
      }
    },
    "randomSeed": 0.5020067737780596
  },
  "applicability": {
    "99426615": {
      "articleId": 99426615,
      "modifications": [{
        "brand": "ВАЗ",
        "model": "ВАЗ-2123",
        "description": "ВАЗ-2123",
        "years": "2000"
      }, {
        "brand": "ВАЗ",
        "model": "ВАЗ-2123",
        "description": "ВАЗ-2123",
        "years": "2000"
      }]
    },
    "__merged": true
  },
  "appraiseCatalogs": {
    "itemsPerPage": 30,
    "items": [],
    "page": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "isFullSearch": false,
    "prices": {},
    "loadingState": 0,
    "searchQuery": "",
    "__merged": true
  },
  "appraiseHistory": {
    "data": [],
    "shortData": [],
    "isShortLoading": false,
    "isShortError": false,
    "isLoading": false,
    "passedShortLoadingOffset": false,
    "skip": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "sorting": {
      "field": 0,
      "order": 1
    },
    "__merged": true
  },
  "appraiseProduct": {
    "appraiseViewMode": 0,
    "currentArticle": "",
    "currentBrand": "",
    "currentArticleId": 99426615,
    "sort": {
      "order": 0,
      "type": 0
    },
    "isSellPrice": false,
    "itemsByDetailUid": {
      "8450_1733640042_3": {
        "detailUid": "8450_1733640042_3",
        "storeId": "10042",
        "region": "Москва",
        "catalogId": 34,
        "catalogName": "Knecht\u002FMahle",
        "catalogUrl": "knechtmahle",
        "shortName": "OC236",
        "name": "Фильтр масляный",
        "changeNumber": null,
        "id": 1733640042,
        "quantity": 2,
        "articleId": 356758,
        "price": 756,
        "minimumSaleSize": 1,
        "deliveryDays": 5,
        "deliveryDate": "2022-01-21T00:00:00",
        "priceId": 8450,
        "isBig": false,
        "failedOrdersPercent": 15,
        "refusalType": 1,
        "isSub": 3,
        "isExpress": false,
        "hasPhotoIcon": true,
        "hasInfoIcon": true,
        "hasApplicabilityIcon": true,
        "rank": 6,
        "originalId": 99426615,
        "sellerAgentType": 0,
        "images": [{
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpeg",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpeg",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpeg",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpeg"
        }, {
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpg",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpg",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpg",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP34\u002FOC236.jpg"
        }, {
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP34\u002FOC236-2.jpeg",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP34\u002FOC236-2.jpeg",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP34\u002FOC236-2.jpeg",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP34\u002FOC236-2.jpeg"
        }],
        "discountPercent": null,
        "isToday": false,
        "isReliableSupplier": false
      },
      "8450_1743752599_3": {
        "detailUid": "8450_1743752599_3",
        "storeId": "10042",
        "region": "Москва",
        "catalogId": 255,
        "catalogName": "Big Filter",
        "catalogUrl": "big-filter",
        "shortName": "GB102M",
        "name": "Фильтр масляный BIG  GB 102M",
        "changeNumber": null,
        "id": 1743752599,
        "quantity": 1,
        "articleId": 901315,
        "price": 353,
        "minimumSaleSize": 1,
        "deliveryDays": 5,
        "deliveryDate": "2022-01-21T00:00:00",
        "priceId": 8450,
        "isBig": false,
        "failedOrdersPercent": 15,
        "refusalType": 1,
        "isSub": 3,
        "isExpress": false,
        "hasPhotoIcon": true,
        "hasInfoIcon": false,
        "hasApplicabilityIcon": false,
        "rank": 10,
        "originalId": 99426615,
        "sellerAgentType": 0,
        "images": [{
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.JPG",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.JPG",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.JPG",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.JPG"
        }, {
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.jpg",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.jpg",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.jpg",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP255\u002FGB102M.jpg"
        }, {
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-1.JPG",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-1.JPG",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-1.JPG",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-1.JPG"
        }, {
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-2.JPG",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-2.JPG",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-2.JPG",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-2.JPG"
        }, {
          "w100": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw100\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-3.JPG",
          "w200": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw200\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-3.JPG",
          "w300": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw300\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-3.JPG",
          "w2000": "\u002Fstatic2\u002Fdetailphoto\u002Fw2000\u002FP255\u002FGB102M-3.JPG"
        }],
        "discountPercent": null,
        "isToday": false,
        "isReliableSupplier": false
      },
      "8450_1770870269_3": {
        "detailUid": "8450_1770870269_3",
        "storeId": "10042",
        "region": "Москва",
        "catalogId": 59,
        "catalogName": "Fram",
        "catalogUrl": "fram",
        "shortName": "PH5822",
        "name": "Фильтр масляный",
        "changeNumber": null,
        "id": 1770870269,
        "quantity": 8
```

Мне в идеале нужно получить два массива: 1 - фирма (в строке обозначается "catalogName"), 2 - номер (в строке обозначается "id")

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Это не html, а json. Родной формат js, странно что вы его не признали

Comment: Он одной строкой?